# UIImage in setBackBarButtonItem in UINavigationBar iphone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am adding image in BackBarButtonItem of navigation bar, image gets in button but image is not scale to fill what would be the issue.

Here is the code i am using and it displays in following way.

```
UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:backImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backAction)];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];
[newBackButton release];
[backImage release];
```

[image]

Actually it should look like, below image.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:newBackButton];
```

Try this :)!

Comment: I had already added leftbar button for Editing purpose and Rightbar button for adding. so, inserting once again leftbar button item will overwrite the previous one. so it can not work. Thanks for reply..

Comment: But, the back-button *always* overrides the left-button, even if you use the built-in back-button...?

Answer (score 0):

```
problem is your image size.check it!
You can also use

//custom back button
    button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(-2, 0, 52, 30)];



    UIBarButtonItem *btnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnItem;
    [btnItem release];
}
```

Comment: please add a comment before downvoting
!

Comment: It's not. Default UIBarButtonItems automatically scale down images to fit so that you're still able to see the button-background.

Comment: There is no issue of image size. even I have tried this one. Thanks for reply. It doesn't work.